# Why does WELD throw an UnsupportedOperationException even though my interface comes with default method implementations?

Tags: java, interface, jboss-weld

A few days weeks RedHat released **JBoss EAP 7.1.0** and so I've started to do some first tests with our application (EAR with Model (JPA), EJB (CDI) and Web). We've used EAP 7.0.7 recently – so the version gap is rather small.

It took only a few seconds to run into the first major problem. WELD now throws an `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsupportedOperationException` without any additional message whenever we try to call a `default` implementation provided by an interface. **Why are default implementations from interfaces not supported?**

**NOTE:** The interface implements this method... it's not the empty method declaration!

*Here is an example for such an interface:*

```
public interface Feature {
    default boolean desiresNewConversation() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

*A simple bean implementing that interface:*

```
@Named
public class MyFeature implements Feature, Serializable {
    public String getName() {
        return "Example";
    }
    // Class does NOT override the default method of the interface.
}
```

*A simple manager class for the UI:*

```
@Named
public class FeatureManager implements Serializable {
    public void start(Feature f) {
        // ...
    }
    public String propagation(Feature f) {
        return f.desiresNewConversation() ? "none" : "join";
    }
}
```

*And the xhtml referencing that method:*

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="#{myFeature.name}" action="#{featureManager.start(myFeature)}">
        <f:param name="conversationPropagation" value="#{featureManager.propagation(myFeature)}" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

This throws the following shortened stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsupportedOperationException: 
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:49)
    at my.package.MyFeature$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.desiresNewConversation(Unknown Source)
    at my.package.FeatureManager.propagation(FeatureManage.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:311)
    ... 107 more
```

This is only a simple example. I'm having this effect on many other default methods provided by interfaces. The `WeldSubclass` won't handle those implementations anymore which made no problem with EAP 7.0.7 and earlier versions.

As soon as I override that method in `MyFeature` those exceptions are gone.

```
@Named
public class MyFeature implements Feature {
    public String getName() {
        return "Example";
    }
    @Override
    public boolean desiresNewConversation() {
        return Feature.super.desiresNewConversation();
    }
}
```

Our application uses several of these default interface implementations and consists of many hundreds of classes implementing those interfaces. **Is there any practical way to solve this other then avoiding default interface implementations at all?**

**PS**: Keep in mind that `WeldSubclass` is a proxy applied by WELD and not my own class. The exception is thrown by the newer WELD implementation of EAP 7.1.0 compared to EAP 7.0.7 where this was legit. And the exception is not even explained with any additional information that might give some reasons for that unexpected change.

Comment: EAP 7.1 uses Weld 2.4.3 I believe.
Your problem looks like a proxy creation problem, but what you describe is simply a `@Dependent` bean using a default method (`@Named` doesn't make a difference in proxy creation) - and this case works for me locally.
Looking at the stack there, it mentions `org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler` from which I would guess you are using interceptors and/or decorators with your classes. This *does change* proxy creation a lot, please update your answer to include all of these.

Comment: Now I recall, in Weld 2.4.5.Final release, there were at least two proxy issues fixed. [WELD-2407](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2407) and [WELD-2405](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2405). This may or may not be what you are running into. Easy way to check this - make a copy of your EAP and try patching it to latest Weld version. Link to patch file and information on how to do that can be seen in the "WildFly patch" part of the [release notes](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/news/2017/12/18/weld-246Final/)

Comment: A few days ago v7.1.1 has been released... I'll check if things have changed.

Comment: There was no component upgrade for Weld in 7.1.1 from what I know, hence I am pretty sure it will blow up again. **If you can put together a simple reproducer**, it would be worth it to create a [JIRA issue](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) for Weld, this could be a bug even in newer versions (have you tried patching to the latest 2.4.x release to verify that?)

Comment: EAP v7.1.1 still has that issue: `Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsupportedOperationException: 
 at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:49)`

Comment: confirmed... EAP v7.1.1 uses `13:38:02,790 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) WELD-000900: 2.4.3 (redhat)`

Comment: Patching EAP directly fails: `[standalone@localhost:9990 /] patch apply /Users/daniel/Downloads/wildfly-11.0.0.Final-weld-2.4.6.Final-patch.zip
Konflikte gefunden: org.jboss.as.jsf-injection:main, org.jboss.weld.api:main, org.jboss.weld.core:main, org.jboss.weld.probe:main, org.jboss.weld.spi:main
Use the --override-all, --override=[] or --preserve=[] arguments in order to resolve the conflict.`

Comment: Ignoring dependencies seems to work but normally isn't a good idea: `14:08:07,730 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000900: 2.4.6 (Final)`

Comment: é voila... works. Used `patch apply /Users/daniel/Downloads/wildfly-11.0.0.Final-weld-2.4.6.Final-patch.zip --override-all` and my original problem is gone. But I'm not quite sure that I should use this approach for production installations.

Comment: That's basically up to you, but if you have a subscription for your EAP, then you can create a customer case and report this along with your findings (and reproducer). They should then proceed to incorporate Weld version improvement in the next patch. In the meantime you can use the version you patched yourself ;-)

Comment: Opened a case for EAP... we'll see.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the bug with a much smaller WAR project and failed so far... so the constellation seems to be a bit more complex. It's not the default method alone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that I've run into https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2407 which is solved with WELD v2.4.5.Final – EAP v7.1.0 and v7.1.1 still use WELD v2.4.3 (redhat).

**Patching EAP v7.1.1 with WELD v2.4.6.Final solved it.** But unfortunately I'll have to wait for an official EAP release.

```
localhost:JBoss-EAP-7.1 daniel$ bin/jboss-cli.sh 
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] patch apply /Users/daniel/Downloads/wildfly-11.0.0.Final-weld-2.4.6.Final-patch.zip --override-all
{
    "outcome" : "success",
    "response-headers" : {
        "operation-requires-restart" : true,
        "process-state" : "restart-required"
    }
}
[standalone@localhost:9990 /]
```

Comment: UPDATE: JBoss EAP v7.1.2 comes with WELD v2.4.7... problem officially solved.